# React TypeError: this.state.List.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Project from "./components/Project.js"
import Form from "./Form.js";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectList: [],
            myProjects: [],
            userList: [],
        };

        this.createProject = this.createProject.bind(this);
    }

    createProject(title, desc, langs, len, exp) {
        this.setState({
            projectList: this.state.projectList.push(
                {
                    title : title,
                    description : desc,
                    language : langs,
                    length : len,
                    experience : exp
                }
            )
        });
    }

    deleteProject(title) {
        const projects = this.state.projectList.filter(
            p => p.title !== title 
        );
        this.setState({projects});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Form createProject = {this.createProject} />
                {this.state.projectList.map((params) =>
                <Project {...params}/>)}
            </div>
        );
    }

    
}

export default App;
```

Hello, when running this, createProject gets passed as a prop to another class, which calls createProject with certain parameters. However, upon trying to render, it returns this error. TypeError: this.state.projectList.map is not a function. Any advice on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` returns the new length of the array, it doesn't return the array. So this code is replacing the array with a number:

```
this.setState({
     projectList: this.state.projectList.push( // <============
         {
             title : title,
             description : desc,
             language : langs,
             length : len,
             experience : exp
         }
     )
 });
```

Numbers don't have a `map` method. :-)

You probably wanted to do this, which creates a new array with the new item added to it:

```
this.setState({
     projectList: [...this.state.projectList, {
         title : title,
         description : desc,
         language : langs,
         length : len,
         experience : exp
     }]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare state like this, you can do something like:

```
        this.setState({
            projectList: [...this.state.projectList, (
                {
                    title : title,
                    description : desc,
                    language : langs,
                    length : len,
                    experience : exp
                }
            )]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi Adam,

    For the current problem below snippet would solve this issue

    this.setState({
                projectList: [...this.state.projectList, 
                    {
                        title : title,
                        description : desc,
                        language : langs,
                        length : len,
                        experience : exp
                    }
                ]
            });

For better understanding refer below link:
    https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove
```